# Trying to install MacPorts

Tags: macports

I've followed the directions in *[Installing MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php)*.

To install MacPorts using the pkg installer. The installation apparently goes fine. For example, it goes through the multi-step process eventually saying "Installation Successful" or something to this effect.

And now there's just the "little" problem that neither of these commands work:

```
man ports

which ports
```

I've checked in `/usr/local`, `/bin`, and `/usr/bin`, and I don't see where this has been installed to. Ideas?

Comment: Read your linked page again? Especially the part where it tells you it defaults to installing in /opt/local/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're in `/opt/local/bin`, so as to not overwrite stuff that came with Mac OS X or that you might have gotten from elsewhere. They won't be in your `$PATH` until you close that Terminal and open another (nothing can alter the environment of a running program except the program itself).

Answer (score 0):

It's in /opt/local/bin. MacPorts updates .bash_profile to include this in the path, but obviously existing shells don't see the updated PATH variable...

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you're trying `ports` but the command is called `port`: See http://guide.macports.org/#using.port